# Naming pattern for the class used by your ViewControllers and contains the business logic

Tags: ios, objective-c

I see a lot of folks (including Apple's sample code) putting all of the business logic in their ViewController classes. However, in an effort to create lighter view-controllers, I  want to put all business logic its own class, with encapsulation, separation of concerns, and unit testability as intended side-effects from this effort.

But what's a good naming convention to use for these kinds of classes that hold the business/application logic and is used by the UIViewController derived class?

Hypothetically, let's say I have a poker game with a class called GameDetailViewController. All of the business logic of what to show or whether the move is valid or not would be placed in a separate class, used by GameDetailViewController.

What's a good name for it? I've seen the term "Service" and "Manager" appended to the class name. Is there a better term?

1. GameDetailService?
2. GameDetailManager?

The problem with 'Service' is that it's often overloaded with whatever remote (aka cloud) service you'd be talking to. Manager: eh.. everything becomes a manager and what does it manage?

I like the design patterns way but I am at a loss to find a good name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would name it for what it does, if its validating hands, then it seems to me it is the GameLogic.h, that way it is easy to read in your view controller when you call for `[GameLogic isValid:hand];` or `[GameLogic is:hand1 greaterThan:hand2];`.  That makes sense to me. And it seems obvious that when you need to ask a question about your game logic, you know where to put it.